# Connection upgrade to WebSocket

Tags: java, rest, web-services

I have poorly documented device that should communicate in two ways `RESTful` and `Websocket`. I'm interested only in functions accessible via `Websocket`. I have opened socket and was expecting some `Json` packet, but got message:

```
GET /api/v1/tasks HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Key: MjhkYjNVdk93M0Fnd3lwdw==
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Host: 192.168.0.80:3701
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: DVR Server
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: Upgrade
```

I suppose this is `RESTful` call and this message is trying to offer to upgrade to `WebSocket`. I'm right? But how to accept this? What I should send as answer? What is the best way to do this in `Java`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking only to accept the websocket handshake, the following code would do the work. 
The first parameter of the **acceptHandshake** function is the writer that writes to the OutputStream of the socket.

```
private void acceptHandshake(PrintWriter output, String secureWebSocketKey) {
    try {
        output.println("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols");
        output.println("Upgrade: websocket");
        output.println("Connection: Upgrade");
        output.println("Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + encode(key));
        output.println();
        output.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String encode(String key) throws Exception {
    key += "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
    byte[] bytes = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1").digest(key.getBytes());
    return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(bytes);
}
```